# OSPOS ( Open Source Point Of Sale ) Not work on localhost with wampserver

Tags: wampserver, opos

I'm new there, sorry if i'm asking by the wrong way and for my english skills,

Since yesterday i try to install OPOS on a windows in wampserver
But all i have after follow the intall instruction

1. install wampserver
2. install composer
3. install nodeJS
4. install grunt
5. make composer install
6. make npm install
7. grunt --force ( but this look like there is not grunt file in this project )
8. create a local database and configure the database.php file to connect it
9. go to your project

And is there that i got my 500 error page.

thanks for helping me to make this project work please.
is an Error 500 page.

Can you tell me how found what's work wrong and help to fix it ?

what information can i share to give a better view of my problem ?

Comment: Does the error log tell you anything? `C:\wamp64\logs`

Comment: this folder is empty

Comment: If that folder is completely empty, then you are not starting WAMPServer. You must have another web server installed

Answer (score 0):

Hellow I had similar problem.

I edited the index.php file and re-defined the constant to development from production.
This enables explicit echo-ing of PHP errors in the browser

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```